# Puppeteer - TypeError: require(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I've started using puppeteer to test a login form, I've tried the following code but I get this errors in vs terminal when I try to run the script

index.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

require('dotenv').config()
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
  // other actions...
  //await browser.close();
})();
```

```
(async () => {
^

TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dev/Desktop/fuserbot/index.js:30:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

The code is the same of the example provided on the puppeteer documentation. As you can see I'm trying to make a cli script. If I try with my custom code, I will get this error instead

index.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

require('dotenv').config();
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    //
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    //
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    //
    page.setRequestInterception(true);
    //
    page.on('request', (request) => {
        console.log(request.url(), request.headers(), request.method(), request.postData());
    });
    //
    await page.goTo('https://www.examplesite.com');
    //
    await page.type('#email', process.env.MY_EMAIL, {delay: 2000});
    await page.type('#pass', process.env.MY_PASS, {delay: 2000});
    //
    await page.click('button[type="submit"]');
    //
    await page.waitForNavigation();

    console.log('New url', page.url());
})();
```

```
    const page = browser.newPage();
                         ^

TypeError: browser.newPage is not a function
    at /Users/dev/Desktop/fuserbot/index.js:12:26
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dev/Desktop/fuserbot/index.js:30:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: For starters, your example does not have semi-colons at the end of your first two lines of code which can cause a problem when you have `(` starting the next line.  Don't leave out your semi-colons.  You get away with it 99.9% of the time, but sometimes it does bite you.

Comment: I;ve always add semicolons at the start of the open brackets ( { [

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that, I didn't know about semicolon problem because usually this will not cause any problem in my ES6 or other node scripts. Thank you for the help

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question for part A, so I'm not sure why that code is there. Just add a semicolon before the IIFE. I can't reproduce your second problem with `browser.newPage()`. Please provide a [mcve].